# Action Bar activity is closed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What is wrong with my code? When I run application on my device/emulator my application is crashed " Unfortunately! Action Bar has stopped"

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    assert mActionBar != null;
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View myCustonView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) myCustonView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("Some Text Here");

    ImageButton mImageButton = (ImageButton)myCustonView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(myCustonView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

}

**NOTE:** I am working in android studio and i have deleted munu.xml file from menu folder and also delete its code from Main class.

Comment: Yous should read the crash log in the Android > Logcat window. Or at least give it to us.

Comment: Try with `getSupportActionBar` instead of `getActionBar` because you are using `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Post your logcat.  Make sure to use `ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();` and to apply a AppCompat Theme to your Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nag and Maisse already provided you proper answers but if these answers not working try this.

Check in style.xml to know which theme are you using for your activity.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

hope this will helps you.

Comment: i am new in programming, what is the location of that file?

Comment: Why should you use the old Holo Theme?

Answer (score 3):

Change following line

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
```

to

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

hope this will helps you.